# jquery display script block as html in textarea

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

I want to have script reference code like this displayed in a textarea so the user can copy it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"/>
```

I'm using jquery and have tried using many solutions found on Stackoverflow or elsewhere but none of them works for me. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var jqueryMin = $('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"/>');
var readyHtml = $('<div>').append($(jqueryMin).clone()).html();
$('#headerHtml').text(readyHtml);
```

readyHtml is empty string though it works when I cloned other html code that is not a script block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined jqueryMin as an object- define it as a string.

```
var jqueryMin = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"/>';
$('#headerHtml').html('<div>'+jqueryMin+'</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pull off what your trying to do is probably something like this:

```
var myCode = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"/>';
myCode = myCode.replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;');
$('#headerHtml').html('<div>'+myCode+'</div>');
```

By completely replacing the brackets, you render it as plain text as far as any browser is concerned. However, when viewing it, the code will appear as intended, and copy/paste will work as expected.